# Dynamic C++ vs other languages - can't call a method on an object without knowing the type

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt

I don't quite understand what a friend of mine said:

> In C++ you can't call a method on an object without knowing the type
>   of the object. It's not dynamic. In Objective C you can by doing
>   something like [object message], in Qt you can do it by using signals
>   and slots. In C++11 you can do it too

My question is: is it correct?

If you can, please explain me in plain English why can't I call a method on an object in C++ (not C++11) if I don't know the object's type.

Comment: You cannot do it in C++11 any more than you could in C++03.

Comment: This would cause a lot of potential run time errors. That is prevented by doing it c++ way..

Comment: `you can't call a method on an object without knowing the type of the object` ... what about `virtual` functions?

Comment: I think you should get your friend to explain to you exactly what they mean.

Comment: C++ (and C++11 too) is statically typed language. You *must* know type of object to call its methods, and type was determined during compiling. However, various design patterns helps to minimize static typing restrictions. In dymanically typed languages (like Objective C) object type will be determined only in runtime - so where is no binding to type in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is correct (mostly.) Object methods in C++ are more or less implemented like normal function calls (except virtual function calls, which are like function pointer calls.) C++11 does not make this any easier, although you can take function pointers and store them in `std::function`, then pass it to something that *doesn't* know the type that can use it. That may be what your friend is referring to, and is similar to Qt signals/slots.

In order to know whether a function call is virtual or not, and the location in the vtable where to locate a virtual function, the type of the class *has* to be known.

In Qt, you can only do this with `QObject`. You can use the `Q_INVOKE` macro to tell `moc` that the function should be accessible via the metacall system. Then, you can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` in order to call it, only knowing that the base class is `QObject` (note that you still need to know the `QObject` type, of course.) Qt is internally just creating meta code that can be used to invoke methods by their names (when they're marked with `Q_SLOT` or `Q_INVOKABLE`, or in a `slots` section.)

Comment: with "the type of the class has to be known" you mean base class or the derived class the pointer is actually referring to?

Comment: The derived class has to be known to know the base class, unless you have a pointer to it from the base type (at which point, of course, you can only use types from the base class and on, not the derived class.)

Comment: You're right, then I always need to know the type of the object to call a method in C++. And that's static typing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The truth is somewhere in between. Strictly speaking, I would say that the claim is wrong.

Basically, C++ is strongly typed, so variables have a defined type for the whole program execution. In dynamic languages, the type of variable may change during program execution.

However, using virtual functions and pointers, you can call a method on an object in C++ without knowing its exact type. In that case, you will have a base languages and several derived classes. When calling a method using a pointer to the base class, you can also store a pointer to a derived class in the variable, and thus you don't know exactly for which class the method will be invoked.

In dynamic languages, when you call a method on an object that is not defined for the object, there is a delegation  mechanism that will (try to) forward the message to an object that understands the message. This is a generic runtime mechanism, that does not exist in C++.

Now Qt is generally strongly typed as is C++. The only way to do things dynamically is by the same mechanism of base/derived classed and vritual functions.

And to be very pointy: calling a method without knowing the type of the object can be seen as in fact not knowing what the method does. Even in dynamically typed languages, you normally have at least an idea of possible types of the object. In that way I would claim there is no application where it is useful to call a method without knowing the type of the object. Note: I'm not saying that dynamic typing is useless (not at all, I'm very happy with Objective C, Ruby, Javascript...) - but I'm saying it's not the case that you don't know anything about the object's type in a dynamic language.